# When I save my json with accent I have wrong text (Qt)

Tags: c++, json, qt, qstring

When I want to create a save in json format (Qt), I use the french accent é : I have this character instead of ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©ro

original (QString) : "sauvegarde numréro 1"
saved (in the json): "sauvegarde numÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©ro 1"

ps: "sauvegarde numéro 1" means "save number 1" in french

save method :

```
QFile saveFile ("save.json");
if (!saveFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text)) {
return false;
}

QJsonDocument saveDoc(m_jsonarray);
return saveFile.write(saveDoc.toJson());
```

saved json :

```
   {
        "created": "2017/9/12-16h19m3s",
        "id": "20170912161903",
        "modified": "2017/9/12-16h19m3s",
        "owner": "johnsmith",
        "title": "sauvegarde numÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©ro 1",
        "world_name": "lava"
    },
```

Comment: Seems to be some Unicode mixup. How is the string encoded in your program? How is it encoded in the file? How are you looking at the file?

Comment: Qt probably defaults in some encoding, which your text editor doesn't seem to recognize.

Comment: What is `m_jsonarray` and how did you get it?

Comment: There is a bug in Qt 5 which Iv reported to Qt:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803384/qt-5-encoding-problems-utf-8-windows-1250-windows-1251

Comment: Where is the input text coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have problem with unicode so use QTextStream because you can set codec for it.
Try this code:

```
QFile saveFile ("save.json");
    if (!saveFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text)) {
        return false;
    }

QJsonDocument saveDoc(m_jsonarray);
QTextStream stream(&saveFile);
stream.setCodec("UTF-8");
return stream << saveDoc.toJson();
```

Comment: Please explain the difference and why it should solve the problem. Code only answers aren't useful.

Comment: From John's example I see that he has problem with unicode so the difference is that I'm using QTextStream because I can setcodec for it.